# Eclipse m2e installation disappear ADT plugin

Tags: android, maven, adt, m2e

I develop Android project using Eclipse and m2e plugin. I am new in using maven. The problem is that when I install m2e plugin it disappears all ADT functional in Eclipse. If I remove this plugin ADT cames back.

I use ADT revision 22.2.1.

And m2e plugin from repository link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the latest version of m2e ? http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master

Comment: Yes I tried both http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases and http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates/master versions.